# Best way to inject config into a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

I'd like my module `something.js` to rely on a config, but I don't want it to `require` the config itself, and I'd like my editor to continue to be able to analyse the module and show autocomplete.  Is there a clean way to do this?  Here's one solution which unfortunately confuses editors.

```
class Something {
    constructor (options) {
        ...
    }

    method () {
        ...
    }
}

module.exports = options => module.exports = exports = new Something (options);
```

And in use:

```
// First use
const something1 = require ('./something')(options);

// All subsequent uses (expecting something1 to deep equal something2)
const something2 = require ('./something');
```

Comment: So, on subsequent calls you'd expect the same instance?

Comment: `const something = require ('./something');`
is it that you also want the module to initialise with these options?

Comment: @james and femioni - yes, sorry it wasn't clear, will edit

Answer (score 0):

Going on the assumption that `Something` should be a singleton, here's how I'd do it:

```
const _inst = null;

const _init = options => {
  if (!_inst) {
    _inst = new Something(options);
  }
  return _inst;    
}

class Something {
  constructor(options) {
  }

  method() {
  }
}

module.exports = _init;
```

First include of `something` would create the instance and then subsequent calls (regardless if options are passed) will always return the same instance.

Only caveat, and this *slightly* differs from your desired usage, this would involve you having to call a function both times i.e.

```
// First use
const something1 = require ('./something')(options);

// All subsequent uses
const something2 = require ('./something')();
```

There are a variety of other ways of doing this too i.e. multiple exports, but the above is probably the closest to the syntax you are after. If you had access to the `import` syntax (which you could via Babel) then the multiple imports would be probably be the neater way i.e. export an `init` function and the instance itself.